# Disadvantage of direct object manipulation with BlueJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, bluej

So I used BlueJ at uni for my first year and noticed how the workbench can be used to create an object and then directly call their methods , this seemed to be a very quick and easy way to test methods on the object and was a quick way of getting inputs for the methods parameters  without having to print the outputs or something to ensure bject is functional.  Having switched to eclipse there doesn't seem to be this option except for downloading a plugin. Is this kind of direct object creation a bad thing? Would it be bad practice to download this plugin and use it for testing?

Comment: Download what plugin?

Comment: An object workbench plugin

Comment: I don't know of any such plugin.

Comment: If you Google object workbench plugin eclipse you'll see what I mean. Basically having the object workbench allows you to directly create temporary objects and you can also call their methods on said objects my question was whether itd be bad practice to use this as a debugging methods

Comment: Debugging and testing is never bad practice. The goal, it seems to me, is to write user-friendly, reusable, easy to maintain code, that meets all user requirements. This requires regression testing and debugging tools. An object workbench is perfect for that. Also, Eclipse has [RCP Testing Tool](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/), which is a decent option as well.